# In Android reactive programming, how to split streamed object data after applying filter?

Tags: android, kotlin, reactive-programming

Having the next data model:

```
data class Response(
        private val success: Boolean, 
        private val error: Error, 
        private val data: Data
)
```

I want to get **Error** object if `success == false` or **Data** object if `success == true` within my `Observable` stream.

I have tried the following approach:

```
Observable.just(Response(true, Error(), Data()))
            .filter { response -> response.success }
            .switchIfEmpty {  } //Wanted response.error here
            .subscribe { response->  } //Wanted response.data here instead of full response.
```

Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved my goal using `flatMap` instead of `filter`, which allows me to implement an `if-else` flow:

```
Observable.just(Response(true, Error(), Data()))
        .flatMap { response ->
            if(response.success) Observable.just(response.error)
            else Observable.just(response.data)
        }
        .subscribe { result->
            when(result) {
                is Data -> //handle data
                is Error -> //handle error
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use sealed classes in this cases

```
sealed class Response {
    data class Success(val data: Data) : Response()
    data class Error(val error: Error) : Response()
}
```

and into your rx observable:

```
   ... //observableChain
   .subscribe { result: Response -> 
        when (result) {
            is Success -> handleSuccess(result.data)
            is Error -> handleError(result.error)
        }
   }
```